# Access VBA Get Quarter From Month Number

Tags: vba, date, ms-access

I am stuck in trying to find the quarter of year number from the month number i.e. i have month number 2 which should be quarter number 1, how do i do this in Access VBA or an access query?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use Choose(MonthNum,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4)

Comment: @Dave you should throw that up as an answer. The only thing it lacks is error/out of bounds handling.

Answer (score 10):

You can use this function:

```
Public Function Quarter(ByVal MonthNumber As Long) As Long

        If (MonthNumber < 1) Or (MonthNumber > 12) Then
                Call Err.Raise(6) ' Value out of Bounds '
        End If

        Let Quarter = (MonthNumber - 1) \ 3 + 1

End Function
```

Comment: `Quarter = (Month(date()) + 2) \ 3` Slightly shorter. :)

Comment: Nice one. I should go back to fractions basics. :-)

Comment: There was a MOD version that would roll whatever number you threw at it to be between 1 and 12. I can't find it and can't figure it out. :(

Comment: Proper syntax now is `Dim Quarter = (Month(Date.Now) + 2) \ 3`

Answer (score 1):

In Excel VBA I like using Choose as sometimes I need to get the financial quarter rather than the calendar quarter.

```
calendar_quarter = Choose(Month(Date), 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4)

' if financial year starts in April - this will get the financial quarter from the current date
financial_quarter = Choose(Month(Date), 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

One liner for Excel:

```
=INT((MonthNo-1)/3 +1)
```

for SQL

```
floor(([MonthNo]-1)/3) +1
```

Answer (score 0):

The format function will convert a date to the calendar quarter:

In string format:
Quarter = Format((Date), "Q")

or use Val to convert to number format:
Quarter = Val(Format((Date), "Q"))